# Route all traffic via VPN except SSH (for using an SSH tunnel)

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

Hi I need to create the following configuration:

I have a VM where I've set up a PPTP connection

```
pty "pptp x.x.x.x --nolaunchpppd"
name username
password password
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
require-mschap-v2
refuse-eap
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
noauth
debug
persist
maxfail 0
#defaultroute
#replacedefaultroute
usepeerdns
```

As you may see without using the default route.

After connecting to the VPN via pon

I tried the following commands

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
ip route add default via [ppp0_gateway_ip] dev ppp0 table 100
```

But this didn't work, please suggest how can I get the desired configuration

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the `OUTPUT` chain, you already have gone through the routing process, so it’s too late in the process to set a mark that is supposed to be used by the routing process.

You should consider consider doing the selection in the routing policy,  something like:

```
ip rule add not ipproto tcp dport 22 table 100
ip route add default via [ppp0_gateway_ip] dev ppp0 table 100
```

Hope this helps.